# ImportError qiskit_ibm_runtime

Tags: qiskit, programming

When I try to import qiskit_ibm_runtime I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'requests.exceptions' (C:\Users\hakan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\exceptions.py)
```

How can I solve this

Comment: I suggest that such a technical issue is raised on Qiskit's GitHub instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree [with @bm442](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/importerror-qiskit-ibm-runtime#comment44175_33450) and this problem was to report in https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime (since I could reproduce it, [I already did it](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/pull/995)).

This problems seem coming from a conflict in your Python environment, that has a `requests` version older than 2.27. You can run this in your environment: `pip install "requests~=2.27"` to fix it.